# Not able to create table with one column and database also not created

Tags: android

I want to create a database in which I want to create a table called "tbl_like" with only one column, "id", but the database is not created with the code below. How  can I solve this problem?

My code for database is this:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dataManager";
    private static final String TABLE_LIKE = "tbl_like";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LIKE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIKE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"  + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LIKE_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIKE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        db.insert(TABLE_LIKE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

}
```

and I called this database handler class in my activity, **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         activity = this;
         DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error please?

Comment: there is no error in logcat but database is not crated by this code when i checked it in ddms.

Comment: if not mistaking database will be created on first call of getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase(). So try calling you method and insert one record. like db.addContact(1);

Comment: ya code is working now.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a line. You didn't add value to ContentValues

```
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  //add this line
    values.put(KEY_ID,contact);
  //
    db.insert(TABLE_LIKE, null, values);
    db.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       SQLiteDatabase dbe;
       try {
            dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                    "/data/data/YOUR.APP.PACKAGENAME/databases/TABLE_LIKE.db",
                    null, 0);
            dbe.close();
            // DB Exists. You can insert.
            DbW = dbe.getWritableDatabase();
            // you should insert with getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // DB doesn't exist. You must create
            String CREATE_LIKE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIKE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"  + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_LIKE_TABLE);
        }
```